# CSS Grid: border between all elements in the grid

Tags: html, css, electron, css-grid

I have an HTML section with the CSS style attribute `display: grid;`.

In it there are a few canvases of a varying amount. Is there an easy way to put a border between these canvases, but not around the whole section?

Their placement within the grid can be any possible placements that CSS Grid allows.

If there isn't a way to do this in CSS, some ideas of how to do this in JS would be awesome, preferably not with jQuery or any other libraries though...

Nothing has to work for any browser other than the latest version of Chromium, since I'm building an app in Electron.

Help would be awesome and thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47887186/3597276

Comment: Oh wow, yes with some slight modifications that would definitely work! Thank you!