# Grid layout with undefined number of columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid-layout, css-grid

I have a HTML  template:

```html
 <ul>
           <li>1
    <li>1
    <li>22
    <li>1
    <li>1
    <li>333
    <li>1
    <li>1
    <li>22
    <li>1
    <li>1
</ul>
```

**ul** container width is determined.

I want to build table style grid layout with **undefined** number of columns.

**Min column** size is restricted by content size of **li**.

**Max column** size could be whole width of the container **ul**.

Here is example I want to achive.
[image]

Is it possible using CSS Grid layout or any other layout?

Comment: Essentially....NO. You don't really have columns here, you have one long wrapping row...so you can't set the column(s) width because there aren't any. If you define the *number* of columns then something could be worked out in CSS-Grid I suspect.

Comment: I thought maybe it could be done with some magic and: `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(???, ???))` I have tried a lot of things and it didn`t work out.

Comment: the `table` element does a great job at this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an *undefined number of columns*, I don't believe it is possible with CSS Grid.

With regard to your comment:

> *I thought maybe it could be done with some magic and: `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(???, ???))`*

That is the logical way to go, but it's a dead end.

The necessary rule would be something along these lines (using `auto-fill` or `auto-fit`):

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(auto, auto))
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(auto, max-content))
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, auto)
```

There are other possible variations using `min-content` and `fit-content()`.

Alas, these cannot work because the `repeat()` function, when used with automatic repetitions, must contain at least one fixed length.

> [**7.2.2.1. Syntax of
>   `repeat()`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#repeat-syntax)
>
> Automatic repetitions (`auto-fill` or `auto-fit`) cannot be combined
>   with **intrinsic** or **flexible** sizes.
>
> - An [**intrinsic**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#layout-algorithm) sizing function is `min-content`, `max-content`, `auto`, `fit-content()`.
> - A [**flexible**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#layout-algorithm) sizing function is `<flex>` (`fr`).

The closest you can get with CSS Grid would be with `grid-template-columns: auto`, an inline-level grid, and a defined number of columns. I'll post this solution for general info.

```css
ul {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

li {
  background-color: white;
}

ul {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>22</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>333</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>4444</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li><!-- added for demo -->
</ul>
```

Here's a separate issue that may arise when building a table with Grid Layout:

- [CSS Grid border collapse (preventing double borders)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47882924/3597276)