# Have border-bottom after grid-row css3

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a grid container whose css is

```
.optionsInnerContainer {
        display: grid;
        // grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr)); /* see notes below */
        // grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
        -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
        column-gap: 10px;
        row-gap: 2em;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

I want to add a border-bottom below every row of grid. I dont know how to do that. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51085555/horizontal-border-across-entire-row-of-css-grid/51085693#51085693

Comment: @TemaniAfif, the link assumes that we have 3 child per row. But my code can have any number of childrens, depen upon available width

Comment: that's why it's called a possible duplicate and I didn't close as duplicate ;) .. it's to give a hint/idea about how you can deal with

Comment: here is a starting idea : https://jsfiddle.net/fLng3emq/9/ .. need to be improved for the last row