# Collapse border using Grid Css?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have constructed a "table"using Divs and grid css and I'm looking how to collapse border using grid css.

Issue: if the above div has a bottom border and the lower div has a top border there is a double border.

Can we avoid it?

```css
.bodyTable {
    grid-template-columns: 220px 220px 220px 220px;
    grid-template-rows: 110px 110px 110px;
}

.displayGrid {
    display: grid;
}

.borderBottom{
  border: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
}

.borderTop{
   border: solid;
   border-width: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="table" class="displayGrid bodyTable">
   <div class="borderBottom">
      A
   </div>
   <div class="borderBottom">
      B
   </div>
   <div class="borderBottom">
      C
   </div>
   <div class="borderBottom">
      D
   </div>
   <div class="borderTop">
      G
   </div>
   <div  class="borderTop">
      H 
   </div>
   <div>
      I
   </div>
   <div>
      J
   </div>
   <div>
      M
   </div>
   <div>
      N
   </div>
   <div>
      O
   </div>
   <div>
      P
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882924/preventing-double-borders-in-css-grid/47883171#47883171

Comment: IMHO it's not a duplicate, I'm looking for a way (property?) to have a single line while maintaining the classes and the borders set

Comment: it's a *possible* duplicate, I didn't close as duplicate .. and there your will find some ideas how you can deal with this because the question is similar

Comment: @Zardo, if this is not a duplicate, tell us how in the text of the question (i.e., not in comments). That is, this is now part of your research.

Comment: I don't want a border on every cell like the linked question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A easy solution would be to give the `borderTop` a negative margin. However this depends on where the class is applied.

```css
.bodyTable {
    grid-template-columns: 220px 220px 220px 220px;
    grid-template-rows: 110px 110px 110px;
}

.displayGrid {
    display: grid;
}

.borderBottom{
  border: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
}

.borderTop{
   border: solid;
   border-width: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
   margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="table" class="displayGrid bodyTable">
   <div class="borderBottom">
      A
   </div>
   <div class="borderBottom">
      B
   </div>
   <div class="borderBottom">
      C
   </div>
   <div class="borderBottom">
      D
   </div>
   <div class="borderTop">
      G
   </div>
   <div  class="borderTop">
      H 
   </div>
   <div>
      I
   </div>
   <div>
      J
   </div>
   <div>
      M
   </div>
   <div>
      N
   </div>
   <div>
      O
   </div>
   <div>
      P
   </div>
</div>
```