# How to style space between items?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Is it possible to style spaces between items in flex?

*Case Scenario:*

1. I have a kind of table/grid
2. I don't want items to grow (`flex-grow: 0`)
3. I don't want `space-between` items
4. If there is not enough remaining space, next item falls to next line

*Example:*

[image]

*Fiddle:*

https://jsfiddle.net/t245o0vr/21/

*Desired effect:*
*I would like to add a border-bottom in those spacing in the end. You think it's possible? Any ideas?*

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 0;
  
  max-width: 470px; /* for the sake of example */
}

.item {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    itemA
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemBitemB
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemCCCC
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemA
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemBitemB
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemCCCC
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemA
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemBitemB
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemCCCC
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tricky problem. Here are some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47882924/3597276

Comment: Hmmm....if there is no element, it can't have a border...and you can't style rows that don't exist.

Comment: `justify-content: space-between;` on `.container`?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet OP stated *"I don't want space-between items"*

Comment: Sorry you edited the question. So the problem is that the border doesn't fill the container?

Comment: Maybe add the lines as a repeating gradient background where the background size is based on em units?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solutions is not based in `flex` (I also would like to know how to solve it with any flex'ish rule) but it works.

Instead of adding border to elements add and absolute positioned `&:after` pseudo-element on every item and hide the overflow in parent

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 0;
  max-width: 470px; /* for the sake of example */
  overflow: hidden; /* <------- new */
}

.item {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 10px;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;   <---- removed */
  position: relative; /* <------- new */
}
.item:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw; /* Bigger enough :P */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    itemA
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemBitemB
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemCCCC
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemA
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemBitemB
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemCCCC
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemA
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemBitemB
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemCCCC
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah...that was my initial thought too. +1

Comment: Cool solution! Can you explain that `width: 600%; depending on items.length`? To note: items width are not fixed, all have width to fit content.

Comment: Any very large width would do...I'd suggest 100vw

Comment: wouldn't 100% enough? :p will try it out and mark as correct asap

Comment: No...because it would 100% of the element not the parent.

Comment: Well, its about how may items per row you expect. In the given example there are 5 elements, so if there was an extra row with just one element 600% probably fit the item-less space. You could just apply a massive number and the result would be the same. +1 for @Paulie_D suggestion of 100vw

Comment: Working as a charm. Thanks folks!

Answer (score 1):

I would consider another way using gradient. The trick is to have a gradient that will get repeated each line to cover each new line that will appear. You simply need to know the height of your line which is based on the `line-height` and `padding`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  line-height:1.2em;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      #0000 0 calc(1.2em + 20px),
      #ccc  0 calc(1.2em + 21px));
  max-width: 470px; /* for the sake of example */
}

.item {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    itemA
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemBitemB
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemCCCC
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemA
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemBitemB
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemCCCC
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemA
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemBitemB
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    itemCCCC
  </div>
</div>
```