# Bootstrap 5 squared columns

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

How do I square a .rows column (e.g col-sm-4)?
I would like to turn each column into widht = height equal columns.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4">I'm squared</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">I'm too</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">yes, I'm too</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap don't have column height out of the box. The column layout grid actually is `flex` ([See reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/)).

#### Extend Bootstrap

To make column have same width and height, the option 1 is add your own CSS the same width unit that appears in Bootstrap.

Example:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%; /* for test, expand height to allow column height works. */
}

[class^="col-"] {
    outline: 1px solid orange;/* for test */
}

.row {
    height: 100%; /* expand height to allow column height works. */
}

.row-sm-4 {
    align-self: stretch;
    height: 33.33333333%;/* same value as width but not exactly same unit in pixels */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4 row-sm-4">I'm squared</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 row-sm-4">I'm too</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 row-sm-4">yes, I'm too</div>
</div>
```

[See it in action on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fd9nw61/)

This will be use same value of `width` but since it is in percentage (%), the result will be different on each screen size and maybe not always square. You maybe use pixel on `height` property but it might not help that much.

#### Grid

The option 2 is use CSS `grid`.

Example:

```css
.grid-column {
    outline: 1px solid orange;/* for test */
}

.container-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
}
.container-grid .grid-column {
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-grid">
   <div class="grid-column">I'm squared</div>
   <div class="grid-column">I'm too</div>
   <div class="grid-column">yes, I'm too</div>
</div>
```

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/3fd9nw61/2/)

Learn more about [CSS grid on css tricks website](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). The answer about CSS [square grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54927248/128761).

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm.